# Can someone travel from outside the Schengen area into the Schengen area just as a transit passenger without holding any Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, paperwork

In the current COVID-19 situation, let's say a passenger wants to travel to a Schengen region airport from outside the Schengen region just for transiting airside to a third country outside the EU/Schengen region. (For example: NewDelhi-Paris-Tokyo)

Is that allowed right now? Can it be done without an Schengen visa and are any special documents required?

Answer (score 1):

If the airport has a transit corridor (which Paris-CDG does), and your nationality doesn't require an airport transit visa, then yes, you can transit.

However, for France, you'll need to complete and print [this form](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/content/download/122386/982118/file/20-05-2020-attestation-de-deplacement-international-derogatoire-hors-europe-fr.pdf), to show the airline during boarding. Select this option:

*Ressortissant de pays tiers, en transit de moins de 24 heures en zone internationale pour rejoindre son pays d’origine et présentant le titre de voyage vers ce pays*

Comment: Your quote is not relevant, because the OP is just in transit to get in a third country (not the *pays d'origine*)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi It's the closest one anyway, and TIMATIC says nothing about non-Schengen -> non-Schengen airport transit being prohibited other than when returning to one's home country.

Comment: I think you mean to suggest that the cited option should be selected (perhaps by ticking or checking), not [crossed out](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cross_out).